# CPU usage increases when broken pipe error

Tags: linux

I am executing a process which is handling SIGPIPE and piping the output through more.
when i press q more exits but the process is running as SIGPIPE is handled.

From the time q is pressed the CPU usage increases and it reaches to ~70% .

Could someone please tell what is the reason behind increase in the CPU usage

Comment: Did you use a debugger like `gdb` or perhaps just `strace` or `ltrace` to find out?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the program just does its job (ignoring the return values of write(2)), as if it was called with >/dev/null rather than more. It is however also possible that it willfully enters an infinite loop at the reception of SIGPIPE. There is no way to tell if you don't reveal what the program is.

Moral of the story: SIGPIPE is meant for exactly this scenario that a pager like more (or less, preferably) exits to tell the output-generating program to also exit because no one is gonna read anymore.

Comment: #!/bin/bash

flag=0;

trap "flag=1" SIGPIPE

while true ;
do
    if [ $flag -eq 0 ]; then
        echo abcde
    fi
    #do someother stuff
done;

Comment: above is the small shell script which is being executed as : "./test.sh | more" and when q is pressed CPU usage starts increasing. Please see if you get something out of it

Comment: That is obviously a programming bug, as you never ever leave the loop.

Comment: I agree but if someone wants to run the process even if SIGPIPE is delivered, not in an infinite loop. What could be the reason behind this increase in CPU usage. I suppose it should not increase. Anyway thanks a lot for your response

Comment: The reason is obviously that programs want to run as fast as they can to complete the task that the programmer sought to solve. SIGPIPE does not change that one tiny bit.